# mongoDB, sum many values query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a list of items, and I want mongoDB return the result of the sum of their price.

```
Schema = {
   _id: ObjectId,
   price: Integer,
}
```

I'm trying using the aggregation framework, but I can't figure out how correctly use it.

Here an example

```
db.items.aggregate([
    {$match: {_id: {$in: [103070,103069]}}}, 
    {$unwind: "$items"}, 
    {$group: {_id: "$items", count: {$sum: "$items.price"}}}, 
    {$project: {_id: 1}}
])
```

Comment: The schema in your question doesn't really match your code.

Comment: Can you post a sample document from your collection, it can better help us to solve your problem. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

you are not correctly using the `$in` operator... `$in` is used to find elements inside an array, in this case you should use `$gte` (greater than equal), `$lte` (less then equal)... Your schema simply don't have `"nodeId"`... `$unwind` is used when you have an array inside the document what I presume is not the case... If i understand the query should be something like:

```
db.items.aggregate([
    {$match : {_id : { $gte : 103069, $lte : 103070 } } },  
    {$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: "$price"}}}, 
    {$project: {_id: 0, count : 1}}
])
```